# Show total Minute Utilization for An hour in PowerBI report

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to do log(ssrs execution log) analysis is powerbi. Requirement here is to show how many minutes utilized for a particular hour based on the request start & end time. Below is example for 4 requests Start & end time with expected result.

1st request 12:00 AM - 12:15 AM

2nd request 12:05 AM - 12:10 AM

3rd request 12:40 AM - 12:42 AM

4th request 12:41 AM - 12:48 AM

So total minute utilization for 12 AM hour should be 15mins(as first two requests overlap with each other) + 8mins (as last two also overlap for some mins) = 23 mins of total utilization at 12 AM.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend splitting up the hour into 60 minutes and counting how many of the minutes are within the time frame of one of the requests.

Something like this logic for a calculated column:

```
Utilization = 
VAR CurrentHour = HOUR ( Requests[Start] )
VAR Minutes =
    GENERATESERIES (
        TIME ( CurrentHour, 0, 0 ),
        TIME ( CurrentHour + 1, 0, 0 ),
        TIME ( 0, 1, 0 )
    ) /*This generates a column named [Value] with 61 rows
        starting from the beginning of the hour.*/
RETURN
    SUMX (
        Minutes,
        IF (
            COUNTROWS (
                FILTER (
                    Requests,
                    HOUR ( Requests[Start] ) = CurrentHour
                        && Requests[Start] < [Value]
                        && Requests[End]   > [Value]
                )
            ) > 0,
            1,
            0
        )
    )
```